# Size of printable file

Tags: print-design, images, file-size

I have to design a file in Photoshop for a leaflet, convert it to tiff and send the same for print. The size of the leaflet will be 13.9cm*21.5cm. Can anybody please tell me what will be the measurements of the photoshop file that i will create?

Comment: Hello Somdutta, welcome to GD.SE. What is the desired resolution, just regular 300 ppi? Going from that, you can calculate it yourself. When in doubt, contact your printer. They might also be able to tell you how much bleed (overflow of your design on the sides of the paper) you will need.

Comment: If you have any questions about this site, have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help] to understand how Stack Exchange works and what you can and can't ask on this site specifically. Welcome again!

Comment: Have you tried creating this file on Photoshop? What happens when you go "File > New"??

Comment: I'd also suggest Illustrator is a far better way to design a leaflet.

Answer (score 0):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in Photoshop to start a new file, then replicate the settings seen in this picture:

[image]